# Angular typehead autocomplete http endpoint callback not being set

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete

I am trying to duplicate this autocomplete in my angular project

http://plnkr.co/edit/t1neIS?p=preview

I copy the HTML and the controller data to my project and it behaves just like the Plunker does. Next i want to try to point the HTTP service to my custom endpoint so i create a url that returns the exact same data structure and headers as in the Plunker example but the autocomplete doesn't work.

original controller code from Plunker example:

```
$scope.cities = function(cityName) {
  return $http.jsonp("http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=JSON_CALLBACK &filter=US&q="+cityName).then(function(response){
    return limitToFilter(response.data, 15);
  });
};
```

My version:

```
$scope.cities = function(cityName) {
  return $http.jsonp("http://localhost/shfofx/PHP/Rest/symbols.php?keyword="+cityName).then(function(response){
    return limitToFilter(response.data, 15);
  });
};
```

data set returned from plunker example (URL in browser):

```
JSON_CALLBACK([
  "San Acacia, NM, United States",
  "San Andreas, CA, United States",
  "San Angelo, TX, United States",
  .....
])
```

data set returned from my endpoint (URL in browser):

```
JSON_CALLBACK([
  "GOOD",
  "GOODN",
  "GOODO",
  ......
])
```

header info from Plunker example:

```
Content-Length →671
Content-type →application/javascript
Date →Sat, 19 Oct 2013 02:43:22 GMT
Expires →0
Server →Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
```

header information from my endpoint:

```
Connection →Keep-Alive
Content-Length →58
Content-Type →application/javascript
Date →Sat, 19 Oct 2013 02:44:30 GMT
Keep-Alive →timeout=5, max=100
Server →Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8x DAV/2 PHP/5.4.10
X-Powered-By →PHP/5.4.10
```

the endpoint in the Plunker example works as desired (see plunker above). When I point the URL to my endpoint the resource is retrieved according to Chromes Resource inspector but the values aren't displayed as autocomplete options?? What can I do or try?

upon further review, Chromes resource inspector shows the working data response is prefixed with:

```
angular.callbacks._2 (the 2 indicating that this is the 3rd call)
```

For my endpoint, the "JSON_CALLBACK" is not being replaced.

i can explicitly set the returned string to contain "angular.callbacks._$" where $ is replaced with the number of the attempt and it works, but of course this is not the right way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the answer was 2 part:

1 - i need to pass the callback=JSON_CALLBACK in the request:

```
http://localhost/shfofx/PHP/Rest/symbols.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&keyword="+cityName)
```

2 - then in my endpoint i need to extract the callback param and prepend it to the beginning of the returned response:

```
$row .= $callback;
$row .= $formattedResponse;
......
print $row;
```